# How to filter data in pandas from a list?

Tags: python, django, pandas, list

I have a list like

```
l = [[Alex,Jan,Fri],[John,Feb,Mon],[Alex,Jan,Fri],[Alex,Feb,Mon],[John,Jan,Mon]]
```

i want to filter out the list for a particular month say "Jan" and the list should look like this

```
l=[[Alex,2],[John,1]]
```

where 2 and 1 are their number of appearances in the list with a particular month using pandas
this is what i tried

```
import pandas as pd
li = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['name', 'month', 'day'])
l = li.filter('month'=Jan).name.count().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Comment: I remove pandas tag, because it seems there is not used pandas structures like Series and DataFrame, only pure python list.

Comment: Are you familiar with list comprehension and `enumerate`? If not, learn them. If yes, use them.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for python solution with `Counter` in list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [list(x) for x in Counter([a for a,b,c in l if b == 'Jan']).items()]
print (L)
[['Alex', 2], ['John', 1]]
```

Pandas solution with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
l = li.query("month=='Jan'").name.value_counts().reset_index().values.tolist()
print (l)
[['Alex', 2], ['John', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with list comprehensions and dicts

```
l = [['Alex','Jan','Fri'],['John','Feb','Mon'],['Alex','Jan','Fri'],['Alex','Feb','Mon'],['John','Jan','Mon']]

target_month = 'Jan'

result_dict = {}

for obs in l:
    if obs[1] == target_month:
        if obs[0] in result_dict.keys():
            result_dict[obs[0]] += 1
        else:
            result_dict[obs[0]] = 1
    
ret_list = []        
for k,v in result_dict.items():
    ret_list.append([k,v])
    
print(ret_list)
```

this will output :

```
[['Alex', 2], ['John', 1]]
```